# Java - How do I loop to read the InputStream until the user makes an input to continue?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, inputstream, outputstream

I have a multithreaded client-server system which works back and forth with the client communicating first and the server replying.

However, for two specific clients, I need them to constantly check if there is data held in the input stream before proceeding when the user makes an input.

The program is a car park management system. When the car park is full(0 spaces available) and a car arrives at an entrance client, the system forms a queue of clients waiting to grant entry. When a car leaves the car park, the first client in the queue is removed and added to a BlockingQueue for that specific entrance client. I have created a direct output output stream for each of the entrance clients. So when a BlockingQueue is not empty, data is taken from this queue and output is sent to the stream of that specific client.

However, the problem is - the entrance client which was queued should automatically read its InputStream and print the data to grant access, but instead it causes an error and crashes. I think what is happening is that when the system first starts, the is the client is stuck waiting to read data which initially doesn't exist because it would require some sort of input at the first stage, causing an error.

How do I fix this so that the client reads and prints the input stream(whether it be specific data such as contains the word "queue") IF there is data available else to continue IF the user makes an input.

I hope this makes sense, I tried to make it as clear as possible.

Server class:

```
public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //Create the shared objects in the global scope...
    int groundFloor = 0; //SET TO 0 FOR TESTING
    int firstFloor = 0;
    SharedState SharedStateObject = new SharedState(groundFloor,firstFloor);

    //Sets up the server socket on port 4444
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    try 
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
        System.out.println("Car Park Server started." + "\n");
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not start server on specified port.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    //Got to do this in the correct order with only four clients!
    ServerThread GroundFloorEntrance = new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept(), "GroundFloorEntrance", SharedStateObject);
    ServerThread FirstFloorEntrance = new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept(), "FirstFloorEntrance", SharedStateObject);
    ServerThread GroundFloorExit1 = new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept(), "GroundFloorExit1", SharedStateObject);
    ServerThread GroundFloorExit2 = new ServerThread(serverSocket.accept(), "GroundFloorExit2", SharedStateObject);

    GroundFloorEntrance.start();
    FirstFloorEntrance.start();
    GroundFloorExit1.start();
    GroundFloorExit2.start();
    serverSocket.close();

    //Loop for granting queued clients access
    while(true)
    {
        BlockingQueue<String> queuedGroundAccess = SharedStateObject.getQueuedGround();
        BlockingQueue<String> queuedFirstAccess = SharedStateObject.getQueuedFirst();
        if(!queuedGroundAccess.isEmpty())
        {
            Socket clientSocket = GroundFloorEntrance.clientSocket();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            try 
            {
                out.println(queuedGroundAccess.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if(!queuedFirstAccess.isEmpty())
        {
            Socket clientSocket = FirstFloorEntrance.clientSocket();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            try 
            {
                out.println(queuedFirstAccess.take());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Client

```
public class GroundFloorEntrance {
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Set up the socket, in and out variables
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    int port = 4444;
    String serverName = "localhost";
    String clientID = "Ground Floor Entrance";

    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(serverName, port);
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.err.println("Don't know about host: " + serverName);
        System.exit(1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: "+ port);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String fromServer = null;
    String fromUser = null;

    System.out.println("Initialised " + clientID + " client and IO connections");

//I THINK THE ISSUE IN THE FOLLOWING STRUCTURE:
    while (true) {
        fromServer = in.readLine();
        if(fromServer != null && fromServer.contains("Queue: "))
        {
            System.out.println(fromServer);
        }

        fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
        if (fromUser != null) {
            out.println(fromUser);
        }
        fromServer = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(fromServer);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 'Causes an error and crashes' is not a problem description.

Answer (score 1):

A problem is in this loop. When you write `fromServer = in.readLine();` it stop execution of your program and waits for data to be entered from server.

```
while (true) {
        fromServer = in.readLine();
        if(fromServer != null && fromServer.contains("Queue: "))
        {
            System.out.println(fromServer);
        }

        fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
        if (fromUser != null) {
            out.println(fromUser);
        }
        fromServer = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(fromServer);
    }
```

What you can do with that? You should read data from server in another thread to prevent blocking main thread while waiting for data. Like that:

```
 new Thread(new MyRunnable(fromServer)).start();
```

And MyRunnable will look like this:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private Scanner scanner;

    public MyRunnable(Scanner scanner) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you will have some questions, please ask.